# How can I use multiple layout files in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to implement a fragment which perform a function that deals with different sets of data and also requires different layout files to render multiple views. I want to implement one common fragment for all the backend operations for data associated with multiple layout views. How can I do so?

Comment: Something like, one activity with multiple xml layout files which I can switch with main xml layout file appropriately

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that you can try this solution

Create a base fragment with all the methods that do some common task which are required for the fragment i.e task as you mentioned in questions(back end operations).

Create as many as fragment you need with different layout and extend the base fragment.

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    }
    //Add your backend operations for data and common methods
}

public class FragmentA extends BaseFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Add your first layout here
    }

}

public class FragmentB extends BaseFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //Add your second layout here 
    }

}
```

Comment: It will work I hope..let me know if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate a different layout based in your own conditioning like so:

```
View mView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(condition_one())
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.condition_one_layout,container,false);
    else if(condition_two())
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.condition_two_layout,container,false);
.
.
.
    return mView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use only one activity i.e; MainActivity. In this main activity, you can load multiple fragments depending upon your data.
Let me show you how.

Suppose your activity_main.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>
```

This activity consist of a Linear Layout which has a fragment inside it.
Now depending on your data, you can load multiple fragments in this inner Linear Layout.

In your MainActivity.java, you can load multiple fragments by applying check :

```
if(message.contains("first_fragment"))
{
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

  final FIRST_FRAGMENT fragment_activity = new FIRST_FRAGMENT();

  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment_activity,"FIRST FRAGMENT");

  fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
else if(message.contains("second_fragment"))
{
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

  final SECOND_FRAGMENT fragment_activity = new SECOND_FRAGMENT();

  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment_activity,"SECOND FRAGMENT");

  fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

Here what I have done is, if your message has a string first_fragment, it must load FIRST_FRAGMENT. Similarly, if your message has a string second_fragment, it must load SECOND_FRAGMENT.

Now, time to implement your FIRST_FRAGMENT.java:

```
public class FIRST_FRAGMENT extends Fragment {

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_fragment, null);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 // buttons or textview of fragment must be initialised here.

}
```

Similarly, SECOND_FRAGMENT will be the same.

Now suppose if you want to check which fragment is currently loaded.
You can do like this.:

```
final FIRST_FRAGMENT myFragment = (FIRST_FRAGMENT) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("FIRST FRAGMENT");

if (myFragment != null && myFragment.isVisible()) {

          myFragment.handleMessage(message);

          // here handleMessage is the function declared in FIRST_FRAGMENT
}
```

Comment: I'm already using a navigation drawer activity. Inside that activity I am already using fragments for each menu item. Now in those fragments I need to implement multiple layouts functionality.